# CDC on AS400 upgrade process

Tags: ibm-data-replication

We have a situation where IBM Data Replication CDC for Db2 on i ver 6.1 (AS400) is installed as the source and Oracle 10.2.x being the target. A hardware upgrade is being scheduled on the source with a new AS400 box coming in, the existing database would be migrated/transferred to the new box. The Oracle box will stay the same and only an upgrade of the CDC agent is to be done. Management Console and Access Server are going to be upgraded too as part of this exercise.

In this scenario, we want to install CDC ver 11.4 on the new AS400 box to take advantage of the latest version and fixes. My queries are, (some might be silly, my apologies)

1. Would this be an install or upgrade on the new AS400 box as the database contains CDC related information?
2. What would happen to the subscriptions, would they have to be created again or an export/import of subscriptions work?
3. Will a refresh have to be triggered?
4. Given the target is the same and source is a new server, what are the implications and how to resolve them?

Answer (score 1):

You should be aware that CDC v6 and CDC v 10.2.x are no longer supported (except for the zSeries 10.2.1 version) so if you have any issues during your migration process you may find it difficult to get support.

In general terms, you should be able to install something like CDC 11.3.3 on the current iSeries in advance of the migration as this version of CDC supports OS/400 6.1 and 7.1 7.2 and 7.3. Then you can save/restore the CDC product library along with all the other libraries. Do not forget to add the TCP/IP listener port service as well. If there is a change of hostname or IP address, you should follow the documented procedure to update the datastore properties in the Access Server https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSTRGZ_11.4.0/com.ibm.cdcdoc.mcadminguide.doc/tasks/handlinghostportforsource.html

Before you restart operations on the new iSeries, you will either need to mark table capture point for all source tables or use SETJRNPOS to manually specify the restart position for replication as the target bookmarks are based on the old journal receiver chain and on the new system this will different

I prefer to upgrade pre-install mainly because it avoids making two changes at the same time. If you had an issue with CDC after migration and then upgrading you would have to determine if it was the new version or the migration that was the cause. However, upgrading the migrated CDC instance immediately after the migration should be OK.

If the IP address or hostname used in the Access Server datastore configuration is changed, you will need to change this following this procedure
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSTRGZ_11.4.0/com.ibm.cdcdoc.mcadminguide.doc/tasks/handlinghostportforsource.html